# HTAccess Rewrite Rules just redirect the first rule

Tags: php, security, url

This RewriteRule works fine:
`RewriteRule ^sellers/?$ /sellers/index.php [NC,L]`

But this others don't

`RewriteRule ^sellers/login/?$ /sellers/login.php [NC,L]`

`RewriteRule ^sellers/logout/?$ /sellers/logout.php [NC,L]`

`RewriteRule ^sellers/profile/?$ /sellers/profile.php?p=profile-content [NC,L]`

Full .htaccess is look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

```
RewriteRule ^sellers/?$ /sellers/index.php [NC,L]
```

```
RewriteRule ^sellers/login/?$ /sellers/login.php [NC,L]
```

```
RewriteRule ^sellers/logout/?$ /sellers/logout.php [NC,L]
```

```
RewriteRule ^sellers/profile/?$ /sellers/profile.php?p=profile-content [NC,L]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.camelando.aaa$ [NC,OR]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^camelando.aaa$
```

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://camelando.aaa/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirect safe url's to correct php files in my local server (.aaa domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing with your .htaccess rewrite rules seems to be due to the order and structure of the rules. The first rule is catching all requests that start with sellers and redirecting them before the other rules have a chance to apply. To resolve this, you need to reorder the rules so that the more specific rules are evaluated first. Here's how you can adjust them:

Place the more specific rewrite rules before the more general ones.
Make sure that the pattern in each rule is specific enough to only match the intended requests.

**Here’s the revised order for your rules:**

```
RewriteRule ^sellers/login/?$ /sellers/login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sellers/logout/?$ /sellers/logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sellers/profile/?$ /sellers/profile.php?p=profile-content [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sellers/?$ /sellers/index.php [NC,L]
```

With these changes, your .htaccess file should now correctly interpret sellers/login, sellers/logout, and sellers/profile before falling back to the more general sellers rule. Each request is evaluated in order, so it’s important to structure your rewrite rules from the most specific to the most general. This way, the intended rule will catch the request before any subsequent, more general rules are applied.

Comment: Thanks my friend, finally works, i spend a lot of time with this, rewrite rules isn't my speciality

Comment: _"The first rule is catching all requests that start with sellers"_ - that really can't have been the case, if the rule pattern was actually `^sellers/?$` - that is anchored at the beginning and end; so the only values it matches are `sellers` and `sellers/`, and nothing else.